# Why won't Namespaces Work in a PHP required file?

Tags: php, class, namespaces, require

This question may sound stupid to many of you, still have I been unable to find any clue in the docs (I did RTFM).

When you set a php variable in a php file and then make use of it in a file you required, it totally works.
But today, While trying to do the same with namespaces, I was getting an unexpected error.

In the main php file :

```
include("./scripts/proj4php/vendor/autoload.php");

use proj4php\Proj4php;
use proj4php\Proj;
use proj4php\Point;

// Initialise Proj4
$proj4 = new Proj4php();

require './functions/myfile.php';
```

in myfile.php :

```
$pointDest = $proj4->transform($projWGS84, new Point($r['coord_x'], $r['coord_y'], $projL2e));
```

This last lane was throwing an Undefined Point class error while it's perfectly fine if I put the line in the main php file.

Both $proj4 and Point() have been set in the main php file, but only the $proj4 was fine in the required php file.

How comes ? What's the logic here ?

Thank you all for your help !

Comment: What is the namespace for your `Point` class?

Answer (score 1):

You created an alias in the main.php file for `proj4php\Point`, but that alias does not extend to other files since it is resolved at compile time, not runtime.

You need to alias/import the class in the file where it is used.   I honestly see no point in importing Point in main.php if you don't use it there.